# JBoss running on DCEVM - IDE claims that code replaced, but behavior doesn't change

Tags: jboss, dcevm

I run JBoss on java7 DCEVM http://dcevm.github.io/

It's possible to Hot Swap any type of code changes from IntelliJ connecting to standalone Swing application (using remote debug; VM startup parameters -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=2222).

But when I try to do something similar when debugging application running on JBoss (connecting debugger remotely same VM parameters as previously) IntelliJ claims that hot code replace succeeded, however application doesn't change behavior as it should.

Do you have any ideas what could be the reason?
Is it connected somehow with the Java EE classloading model?

Has anyone experienced such problem?

Is it possible to hot swap code with DCEVM in JBoss using remote debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following project: https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent. It uses DCEVM and solves hotswapping problems inside many java frameworks (Spring, JSF etc..)

Comment: I gave up some time ago, but this tool seems to be useful. Thank you!